# Removing the rows that columns don't match with the same values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a data frame that looks like this.

This is what I have:

```
   V1                 V2          V3
hello                 0            0
nice                  0            1
meeting               1            1
you                   1            0
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
   V1                 V2          V3
hello                 0            0
meeting               1            1
```

So basically I want to remove the rows that V2 and V3 column does not match with the same numbers. I only one to leave rows that V2 and V3 column share the same values either 0 or 1. How can I do this? 
Please help me....
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

`df.loc[df.V2 == df.V3]`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted logic - get all rows with same values in both columns:

```
df = df[df.V2 == df.V3]
```

Alternative with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare:

```
df = df[df.V2.eq(df.V3)]
```

Next alternative with [`DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = df.query("V2 == V3")
```

Comment: what does 'eq' do? I tried to follow your code but it gives an error on 'V2eq'

Comment: @dkdlfls26 - my typo, missing `.`